# Could I have problems if I create directories inside /home?

Tags: linux, user-profiles, home-directory

On a laptop used exclusively by me, whit only one personal user account (i.e. let's call it `myuser`), there could be any problems or annoyances in creating directories inside `/home` but external to `/home/myuser`?

As an example, let's say that I want to create something similar to this:

```
/home/appimages
/home/lamp
/home/myuser
```

in order to put a Bitnami LAMP stack and Appimages programs outside the "regular", "everyday" home directory; all of this for the sake of decluttering and having a structure where it is easier to manage backups, file indexing, and other things without resorting to exclusion patterns.

Assuming that no more personal users will be created (and in the remote possibility, without using the same names of these directories), there could be problems, drawbacks, random annoyances, that I've not thought of with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

No problems but IMHO not very "natural". `/home/xxx` is supposed to be the home directory of `xxx`. Why not create these directories under `/` directly?

If you made a distinct FS for `/home` and find you have room to spare there, a better hierarchy IMHO is to have `FS/home` and `FS/other` directories in that FS, and link/bind-mount `FS/home` on `/home/`.